# Typescript function not being run

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I have the following typescript file in Nativescript:

```
import { Observable } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { Color } from "tns-core-modules/color";
import { request, getFile, getImage, getJSON, getString } from "tns-core-modules/http";

export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {

    items: {
        name: string,
        desc: string, 
        price: string, 
        imageSrc: string, 
     }[];

    getData = getJSON("http://localhost:3000/items").then((r: any) => {
        this.getData = r; // assign it from the response when successful
            console.log("blarg!!!")
        }, (e) => {
    }); 

    onItemLoading(args) {
        // hack to get around issue with RadListView ios background colors: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/196
        if (isIOS) {
            var newcolor = new Color("#e6e6e6");
            args.ios.backgroundView.backgroundColor = newcolor.ios;
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The issue I am seeing is that getData is never being called/ran. How do I call/run the getData function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not type-safe and you probably don't mean to do this.

```
getData = getJSON("http://localhost:3000/items").then((r: any) => {
    this.getData = r; // assign it from the response when successful
        console.log("blarg!!!")
    }, (e) => {
});
```

If you expose the type from the initial assignment, you've got:

```
getData: Promise<void> = ...
```

If you expose the type from the inner assignment, you've got:

```
this.getData = r as any;
```

It is very likely that neither of these is actually a function. Instead, what you probably wanted to do was something more along the lines of:

```
data: any;

constructor() {
    super();

    getJSON("http://localhost:3000/items").then((r: any) => {
        this.data = r; // assign it from the response when successful
            console.log("blarg!!!")
        }, (e) => {
    });
}
```

Comment: OK, this works, though I am getting an error...does anyting look to be wrong with the getJSON statement to you? I have json-server running locally.

Comment: That will depend on the error that you're getting. Without knowing any details, I'm going to guess it's one of the following: 1. NativeScript is intended to run on a mobile device. If your server is on your dev machine, it won't be referenced by `localhost`. 2. On iOS, URLs generally need to be accessed through `https`, not `http`. You can set properties in your `Info.plist` to avoid this.

Comment: Ian, you nailed it! When I did console.log(e) the error being thrown was `Error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it higher up the stack. Or, If you want `getData` to run when the object is created, call `getData()` in your constructor.

Comment: Can you share an example? This does not work https://pastebin.com/j0UwyrRZ